# How to specify branch path in --destination-dir?

Tags: git, asciidoctor

I'm trying to use `--destination-dir` to run the command `asciidoctor --destination-dir='test branch path' test.adoc` so the output is in the branch 'test'. Anyway I can do this?
Does the URL work? e.g. **https://github.com/repo/tree/test**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know branches are not directly exposed via a directory, and I don't think there is a way to do this from within asciidoctor, since git and asciidoctor are two seperate things.

I would recommend doing it with a shell script, with something like:

```sh
git checkout -b test
asciidoctor --destination-dir=output test.adoc
git add output
git commit -m "Output"
git push
```